# How to force overflow-ed element to start at top

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I have a `<mat-drawer-container>` that contains a `<mat-selection-list>`. Whenever the `<mat-selection-list>` has enough elements to overflow, the scrolling is not starting at the top when the elements are rendered. It's starting at the first element in the list, which hides the `title` and `subtitle`. Is there a way to force the scroll to start and the top?

[edit] I'm aware that I could leverage something like a scrollTo(), but it seems hack-y, and I'm trying to determine the best-practice approach for this.

[image]

```html
<mat-drawer-container class="container">
    <mat-drawer #drawer (openedChange)="onOpenedChange($event)" class="sidenav" mode="push" opened>
        <p class="drawer-title">Data Validation</p>
        <p class="drawer-subtitle">{{integrationName}}</p>
        <mat-selection-list [multiple]="false">
            <mat-list-option (click)="getTableNames(date)" (click)="drawer.toggle()" class="date-item" *ngFor="let date of dataServiceDates">
                {{date}}
                <mat-divider></mat-divider>
            </mat-list-option>
        </mat-selection-list>
    </mat-drawer>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<mat-selection-list>` kind of pseudo-selects the first item in the collection of `<mat-list-option>`'s. This can be disabled by defaulting all of `[selected]` `Input()`'s to `false`

The fix was put in place like so:

```html
<mat-drawer-container class="container">
    <mat-drawer #drawer (openedChange)="onOpenedChange($event)" class="sidenav" mode="push" opened>
        <p class="drawer-title">Data Validation</p>
        <p class="drawer-subtitle">{{integrationName}}</p>
        <mat-selection-list [multiple]="false">
<!--here--> <mat-list-option [selected]="false" (click)="getTableNames(date)" (click)="drawer.toggle()" class="date-item" *ngFor="let date of dataServiceDates"> 
                {{date}}
                <mat-divider></mat-divider>
            </mat-list-option>
        </mat-selection-list>
    </mat-drawer>
</mat-drawer-container>
```